# Get compilation files list from proj file DotNet Core

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

In `DotNet Framework` we could find out what files are needed for the compilation process by parsing `.csproj` and looking for all XML tags with `<Compile Include="FileNameRelativePath">` and `<EmbeddedResource Include="FileNameRelativePath">`

But unfortunately for me, `DotNet Core` doesn't have this information, because this information is defined now in the specific `SDK` (WEB, WindowsDesktop, etc...).

**My goal is**: regardless of project language (`c#` or `f#`) or type (`WEB`, `WPF` etc) I need to get a list of files that are needed for the compilation process. I expected that I could do that using msbuild, but I couldn't find anything like that. Any thought?

Comment: Parsing the .csproj is really msbuild's business, would be quite tedious to use something else for that. Aren't you just looking for a target with `<Message Text="Compile items = @(Compile)"/>` which will simply print the list? (which still works for SDK projects: they just automatically populate the itemgroup with `*.cs` or equivalent)

Comment: @stijn Unfortunately it shows only .cs files. For c++ projects, it doesn't return anything. Also, it doesn't have cshtml files for example. But you are right, it seems to be the right direction to dig, just variable doesn't seem to be the one..

Comment: It shows only .cs files because the others you mention use a different itemgroup (e.g. `ClCompile` for C++). There isn't a single 'anything which might get compiled or interpreted' variable, that would also be a mess to work with. Only way to get that is list each seperately (or combine them into one list yourself). Perhaps explain why you need such list?

Comment: @stijn I need to recompile a project automatically once it's changed, but the process shouldn't be invoked if a non-embedded resource file is changed or the file that is in the project directory but is excluded for some reason since such files are not part of the compilation process.

Comment: isn't this goal already supported by `dotnet watch run`?